# GridView Handle OnTouch and OnClick events

Tags: android, gridview, calendar, onclick, touch-event

I want to write a calendar.
for that purpose, I have a GridView with an Adapter that fill it with a relativeLayout (that contains a textview to display the day) in each cell.

The GridView displays only one month.

when i click on a day - I have an onClickListener on each cell to display the day with a Toast(for the test only) and it's work.
Now I would like to switch month by swipe on the gridview to go to the next month.
The probleme is that the gridview not get the onTouch event when i touch the cell...

Anyone can help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to show the next/previous month on swipe, you can use something like `ViewPager`

Comment: Thank you for your response
can i use a display like a gridview with a viewpager ?

Comment: Sure. You can make use of `Fragment`s